# position absolute is not working for bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a drop-down which is not working(onclick, dropdown menu isn't appearing) for `position:absolute` but it is working for `position:relative`. The problem with position relative is that the drop-down menu is not responsive as shown in the below image.the drop-down is changing its place based on the value of the drop-down.As you can see in the image the drop-down menu isnt visible completely. I want that drop-down menu to be in proper position either using `position:absolute` or `position:relative`. thanks in advance.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-right: -15vh;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #337ab7;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="position:relative">
  <h3>

    <b class="col-sm-12" style="width: 50%;">{{ editMode ? 'Edit' : 'Create'}} Test <i> - [in 3 STEPS]</i></b>
    
<div *ngIf="test.questions?.length  == test.no_questions">
      <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="float: right;">{{selectedCourse}}&nbsp;
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size: 0.7em; font-weight: 600;"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let item of user['subscribed_courses']" 
      [ngStyle]="{'display':item.acr == selectedCourse ? 'none' : 'block' }"
      (click)="selectCourse(item.acr)">{{item.acr}}</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
  </h3>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: This code is not running at all and won't run like this. Only post the 'html', css part that is relevant and remove the rest of code - so someone might try read and help you.

Comment: Your code with position absolute seems to work in this jsfiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/x3grj8fz/

Comment: not working in mine. i have tried several times.